# Let $S = [a,b]$. Let $X$ be a subspace of $C(S)$ that is closed in $L^2(S)$. Show that the sup-norm and the $L^2$ norm are equivalent on $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $S = [a,b]$. Let $X$ be a subspace of $C(S)$ that is closed in $L^2(S)$. Show that the sup-norm and the $L^2$ norm are equivalent on $X$.

Does this mean that $X$ is a subset of both $C(S)$ and $L^2(S)$? If it is a subspace of $C(S)$, does that mean that it is a linear space, closed over vector addition and scalar multiplication? If so, it would also be a subspace of $L^2(S)$ as well, right? When it is "closed in $L^2(S)$" does that mean it is closed in the sense of containing all limit points?

The sup-norm and $L^2$ definitions are:

\begin{align*}
  {\lVert f \rVert}_2 &= \left\{ \int_\Omega {\lvert f(x) \rvert}^2 \, dx \right\}^{1/2} \\
  {\lVert f \rVert}_\infty &= \text{ess sup}_{x \in \Omega} {\lvert f(x) \rvert} \\
\end{align*}

What would it mean to show that these are equivalent? The norms clearly won't necessarily have the same value for the same function.

Comment: It's a general fact. If a Banach space $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ is a closed subspace of another Banach space $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and for $y\in Y$ we have $\|y\|_X\le c\|y\|_Y$ then the norms $\|\cdot \|_Y$ and $\|\cdot \|_X$ are equivalent on $Y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given that $X$ is closed in $L^{2}$ norm but this implies that it is also closed in sup norm: If $(f_n) \subseteq X$ and $\|f_n-f\|_{\infty} \to 0$ then $\|f_n-f\|_{2} \to 0$, so $f \in X$. Now apply Open Mapping Theorem to the identity function $: (X(\|.\|_{\infty}) \to  (X,\|.\|_2)$.

Comment: Can you explain why $X$ being closed in the $L^2$ norm  implies it is closed in the sup-norm? And why does convergence in the sup-norm imply convergence in the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: @clay $\sqrt {\int_a^{b} |f_n-f|^{2}}\leq \|f_n-f\|_{\infty} \sqrt {b-a}$.